# Generating a list of all the lines in a text file using the with statement

Tags: python

I know you can populate lists using a one line "x for x in y" style loop, is it possible to do it using with?

I tried pulling all lines from a text file into a list and it didn't seem to work, at least not the way I tried it.

I tried:

```
lines = [ x with open("text.txt").readlines() as x]
```

and

```
lines = [ x.readlines() with open("text.txt") as x]
```

which would seem to use the same format but gives me an invalid syntax error. I appreciate I could do it with a for but I'd like to save myself the job of using a close()

Is this possible or am I grasping at straws? This is Python 2 by the way.

Comment: Not seeing how, that's an explanation of how with works rather than whether you can manipulate the shape of a with statement, you can manipulate the shape of fors and ifs. I appreciate with is a statement rather than a loop but it can act as one which is why I was wondering about the potential shape change.

Comment: Although I do now understand that it is a statement rather than a loop.

Comment: Well, the *second question* in that question was asking for *What do you use it for?*

Comment: I think you misread, sorry. This was entirely about whether you can reshape the with statement. I've used with comfortably before and after re-examining it with the replies, I can see that while I was using it right prior to my attempt at a one-line reformat I didn't fully understand it, so that would have answered the IMPLIED question but still wouldn't have answered the PRIMARY question which was can you reformat with statements into one liners in a similar way to for loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this one-liner works:

```
with open('file.txt') as fobj: lines = list(fobj)
```

using `with` with pythonic syntax, you need two lines:

```
with open('file.txt') as fobj:
    lines = list(fobj)
```

Here `fobj` is an iterator that allows efficient line-by-line iteration. Converting it into a list with `list(fob` has the same effect as `fobj.readlines()`.

Comment: Do you know whether there is any difference between `list(fobj)` and `fobj.readlines()`? I have only been using the latter until now.

Comment: Thanks. I did wonder. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: As far as I know, here is no difference.

Comment: @MikeMüller Awesome, learned something new. +1

Comment: @timgeb That's what this site is all about. My approach is learning by teaching. :)

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensions can only use the `for` statement, not the `with` statement. You can only do (and there's no reason why you shouldn't)

```
with open("text.txt") as x:
    lines = x.readlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

`with` is a context manager and can't be put in one line. And as BDFL once said, "Why do we need to save lines? We are not Perl." (as in, no we don't need to save lines.)

You could just do it in two:

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as x:
    lines = x.readlines()
```

Answer (score -4):

```
lines = open("test.txt").readlines()
```

There's no need to use a list comprehension here, and the file isn't kept open when you're done anyway.

Btw, it can be combined with a list comprehension if you need it, something like:

```
lines = [l.strip() for l in open("test.txt").readlines()]
```

Comment: You still need to close the file afterwards though.

Comment: Actually, no. Since no reference to the file object is kept, it will automatically be cleaned up. In the case of file objects, this also means the file handle will be closed

Comment: That the file is closed after the file object goes out of scope is an implementation detail of cPython's use of reference counting, and you shouldn't rely on that behaviour. It's definitely not true for other python implementations like pypy or jython.

Comment: Then why have the `with open(file) as fileobject` construct at all? Relying on the garbage collector to close your file handles is bad practise.

Comment: I'll admit i have no experience with pypy or jython, but frankly I don't see why it would be strange to at least expect this to work. I'm not keeping a reference to an object, so I'm done using it. Ergo, no need to keep a file handle open. Call me lazy, but I'm used to things making that much sense in python. I guess there's no point in complaining if my own ignorance was the problem, but I'm surprised that it's not this intuitive across all implementations. Anyway, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: From [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Explicit is better than implicit."  - It is better to explicitly close the handle that rely on some background process do (maybe) do it for you. `with` does this.

Comment: That's a good point :)